# manager's remove function delete two object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Symfony 6.4

Here is my architecture is :
PROPOSITION : PK(TESTID,RUBRIQUEID,QUESTIONID,PROPOSITIONID)

I'm trying to delete a proposition with Symfony's EntityManagerInterface but two propositions are deleted:

```
$proposition = $manager->getRepository(Proposition::class)->findOneBy(['TESTID' => $testid, 'RUBRIQUEID' => $rubriqueid , 'QUESTIONID' => $questionid,'PROPOSITIONID' => $propositionid]);
        $manager->remove($proposition);
        $manager->flush();
```

The PROPOSITION WITH (TESTID = 1 RUBRIQUEID = 1 QUESTIONID = 1 PROPOSITIONID = 1)
And the PROPOSITION WITH (TESTID = 1 RUBRIQUEID = 1 QUESTIONID 2 = PROPOSITIONID = 1).

The propositions might be getting deleted because they share the same propositionID but have different TESTIDs. When I debug using dd(), I only see the first proposition. I'm not sure why both propositions are getting deleted

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Strange question, but aren't you doing this in any sort of loop?

Comment: Only using these three lines and all the propositions with the same ID are deleted. No loop

Comment: Have you used any cascade in the definition of your entity classes?

Comment: Hello The Rock! I haven't used cascade in the definition of my entity classes, I'm using it right now but I've had the same problem without it.

Comment: Could you give some more context in your question then please? Like the Proposition class and the what $testid, $rubriqueid, $questionid and propositionid come from? And the fact that you only see one proposition in your dd is normal, he dumps the first and then dies, try using dump instead.